# C++ compiling errors

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

First of all here is my **C++** source:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void number(int x){
    cout << "Number is: " << x << endl;
}

int main(){
    cin >> int x;
    number(x);
    return(0);
}
```

Upon compiling I get the following errors:

- **file.cpp: In function 'int main()':**
- **file.cpp:9:9: error: expected primary-expressing before 'int'**
- **file.cpp:9:9: error: expected ';' before 'int'**
- **file.cpp:10:9: error: 'x' was not declared in this scope**

I compile and run this successfully in *CodeBlocks* but under Ubuntu with **gcc** or **g++** things fail.

Comment: There's no way any compiler successfully compiled and ran this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
int main(){
    cin >> int x;
```

to

```
int main(){
    int x;

    cin >> x;
```

Comment: I still get a bunch of errors and end up with "ld returned 1 exit status"

Comment: @amatecha I do not see other errors in the posted code. What are new error messages?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/KNWFhWJY

Comment: @amatecha Those are linker errors. Check your linker options and make sure the standard library is linked in.

Comment: @amatecha They are not compilation errors. Your linker does not see where there is the standard library. You should turn in your environment.

Comment: @amatecha, Also make sure it's `g++`, not `gcc`.